# Using props value in linear-gradient in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to use the color which is in props for the linear-gradient,Something like this

```
const minColor = this.props.data.myresources ? this.props.data.myresources['min'].color : this.props.data.gradeColor;
const maxColor = this.props.data.myresources ? this.props.data.myresources['max'].color : this.props.data.gradeColor;

<div className="filler"
    style={{
    width: `${this.props.data.maxGrd}%`,
    backgroundImage: 'linear-gradient(to right, `${minColor}`,`${maxColor})'
}}>
</div>
```

It show a empty bar with no color, where as I'm getting the color values in the const, is there any way to implement this?

Comment: Should be `backgroundImage: \`linear-gradient(to right, ${minColor}, ${maxColor})\``

Comment: Tried it.... its not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases in which you are wrong, 
1. Use proper gradient styling syntax according to react, ex:

Replace

```
'linear-gradient(to right, `${minColor}`,`${maxColor})'
```

By

```
`linear-gradient(to right, ${minColor} , ${maxColor})`
```

2. You didn't provide height to div, So its not showing anything. Or you can provide text inside div, then it will automatically take height for div according to text inside div height.

I am attaching a code sandbox link here, that is a working example where you can identify your mistakes.

[Link to see working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vvx4pv00z3)

Comment: I tired with this already and its not working from the props.I have specified the height in css, so the bar is displayed without any filling colors.

Comment: Can you show , how you are using gradient minColor and maxColor?

Comment: The same way you have written, instead of putting static value, the colors will be coming from props is the only difference.

Comment: On printing the linear gradient , I'm having something like this ,linear-gradient(to right, #047a9c, linear-gradient(45deg, grey, grey 48%, transparent 48%, transparent 52%, grey 52%)) do have nay idead how to have lineader-gradient inside another one?

Comment: You can use multiple backgrounds like this [Link for example](https://codepen.io/mukulk133/pen/Rqbdya)

Comment: Thank you so much...it was helpful.